# R highly efficient recursion

Tags: r, recursion, memory-efficient

Let us assume we observe data over a 1-year horizon on a monthly basis (k = 12). Let us also assume the following recursive structure (example below).

I wonder, how this structure can be programmed most efficiently considering the following aspects (Efficiency will be absolutely necessary):

- The period of 1 year is for simplicity and is generally not fixed at this value. Accordingly, this value must be redefined each time,
- The monthly calculations have to be stored (I thought of a list?) because I need the specific values for further calculations.

MWE:

```
beta = c(0.95, 0.89, 0.23, 0.96, 0.98, 0.79, 0.99, 0.85, 0.97) 
dim(beta) <- c(3, 3)
phi = c(0.45, 0.12, 0.98, 0.66, 0.79, 0.24, 0.33, 0.19, 0.27)
dim(phi) <- c(3, 3)
```

(In general, the parameters beta and phi are not observed but have to be estimated, so this is just an assumption for simplicity.)

In k-1 we calculate a matrix of the following form:

```
K1 <- beta %*% t(beta)
```

In k-2 we have a similar expression, but now it also depends on the previous value times phi:

```
K2 <- beta %*% t(beta) + phi %*% K1
```

In the period k-3 it is the same as in k-2, only that K1 changes to K2. So from here on it is recursive and repeats itself. So for the last observation (k-11) it is the same formula with K10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you always need the term `beta %*% t(beta)`, so store it instead of calculating it in each iteration:

```
btb <- beta %*% t(beta)
```

Now you can use the `Reduce`-function.

```
Reduce(f = function(kPrevious,someOther) {btb + phi %*% kPrevious},
       x = 1:10,
       init = btb,
       accumulate = TRUE
)
```

The argument `accumulate=TRUE` saves all the intermediate results.

An alternative would be using simple `for`-loop. But this is not as eficient as `Reduce`. (Although it does the "same"):

```
  history <- list(btb)
  for(k in 1:10) {
    history <- c(history,list(btb + phi %*% history[[length(history)]]))
  }
  history
```

For calculating some benchmarks, lets put everything in a function, dependent on the number of iterations:

```
ff0 <- function(n=10) {
  Reduce(f = function(kPrevious,someOther) {btb + phi %*% kPrevious},
         x = 1:n,
         init = btb,
         accumulate = TRUE
  )
}

ff <- function(n=10) {
  history <- list(btb)
  for(k in 1:n) {
    history <- c(history,list(btb + phi %*% history[[length(history)]]))
  }
  history
}
```

Now, lets see whether the two functions give the same output:

```
all(mapply(FUN = function(x,y) {all(x==y)},ff0(),ff()))
```

To get a benchmark, lets use `microbenchmark`:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff0(),ff())
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr  min    lq   mean median    uq  max neval
# ff0() 20.6 22.80 25.388   24.1 25.20 79.2   100
#  ff() 11.4 12.25 13.922   13.0 13.65 80.0   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff0(100),ff(100))
#Unit: microseconds
#     expr   min     lq    mean median     uq   max neval
# ff0(100) 163.1 172.50 191.193 186.35 198.00 320.6   100
#  ff(100) 143.0 151.45 169.125 164.75 174.05 296.1   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff0(1000),ff(1000))
#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
# ff0(1000) 1.5680 1.62505 1.698665 1.67135 1.74185  2.6058   100
#  ff(1000) 4.6626 4.77065 5.293329 4.87640 5.10260 11.2255   100

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff0(10000),ff(10000))
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
# ff0(10000)  15.9035  16.4428  17.28437  17.0618  17.71085  22.1506   100
#  ff(10000) 468.8924 484.7448 494.79808 489.4221 496.60075 581.0389   100
```

As we can see, the `for`-loop implementation seems to to better on calculations with a relatively small number of iterations. But as the iterations go up, `Reduce` becomes faster. I think the reason is that `Reduce` produces some more overhead than the simple `foor`-loop, but this overhead doesn't weigh much once it is created.
So it is up to you which implementation you wil use.

Comment: if beta matrix is huge then ```tcrossprod(beta)```  instead of ```beta %*% t(beta)``` will be a lot faster